# Is it possible to bind with collection and if so how?

Tags: java, javafx, beans-binding

I have `List<CheckBox>`. I need to bind the `selected` property of them to a `List<Boolean>`. Is there any way to achieve it. If so how?

Comment: You should add a tag corresponding to the graphic library you are using. Is it maybe JavaFX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java 8 you can loop to the list with a stream:

```
List<Boolean> booleans = 
    checkBoxList.stream().map(checkbox -> checkbox.isSelected()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Of course, this not binding. It will copy the value to the new lists. If you change the values in booleans, it won't in the original checkBoxList object. boolean and Boolean are both immutable.

Edit: Maybe your UI-Framework can handle List<.Checkbox> directly...